# Using mdframed style within \declaretheoremstyle to change title

Tags: mdframed, thmtools

I am using [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) to create an example environment using `\declaretheoremstyle` and `\declaretheorem`. 
I am also modifying the style using the `mdframed` key, to create a frame, shade the background of the example environment, and give it rounded corners.
I also want to format the title text, i.e., `Example 1` and put a coloured line underneath the title before the example, but I can't figure out how to do this.
I can see that it can be done using \newmdenv to create the example environment, but I want to stick with `\declaretheoremstyle` and `\declaretheorem`, since I am using it for all my other environments.
Can anyone assist?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

% example style
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries, 
    notebraces={[}{]},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace=\newline,
    spacebelow=\parsep,
    spaceabove=\parsep,
    mdframed={
        backgroundcolor=red!20, 
            linecolor=red!30, 
            innertopmargin=6pt,
            roundcorner=5pt, 
            innerbottommargin=6pt, 
            skipbelow=\parsep, 
            skipbelow=\parsep } 
]{myexamplestyle}

% example environment - thmtools
\declaretheorem[
    style=myexamplestyle,
    name=Example,
    numberwithin=chapter
]{example}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}[Example 1]
something
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

% example style
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries, 
    notebraces={[}{]},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace=\newline,
    postheadhook={\textcolor{red}{\rule[.6ex]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}\\},
    spacebelow=\parsep,
    spaceabove=\parsep,
    mdframed={
        backgroundcolor=red!20, 
            linecolor=red!30, 
            innertopmargin=6pt,
            roundcorner=5pt, 
            innerbottommargin=6pt, 
            skipabove=\parsep, 
            skipbelow=\parsep } 
]{myexamplestyle}

% example environment - thmtools
\declaretheorem[
    style=myexamplestyle,
    name=Example,
    numberwithin=chapter
]{example}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\begin{example}[Additional text]
\lipsum[4]
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Didn't know the key `mdframed` of `thmtools` ;-) -- Nice.