# LaTeX Error: No counter 'refsection' defined generated by \listoftheorems

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems, counters, amsthm, newtheorem

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem. Somehow I'm getting the following error message

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'refsection' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \defcounter {refsection}{0}
                               \relax
```

The error appears whenever I add `\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={Example}]` to

```
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Examples}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Examples}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={Example}]
```

I borrowed the example from this link [Using mdframed style within \declaretheoremstyle to change title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110244/using-mdframed-style-within-declaretheoremstyle-to-change-title) to create my **list of examples** as follows

```
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    notebraces={\hfill}{},
       bodyfont=\normalfont,
       headpunct={},
       postheadspace=\newline,
       postheadhook={\textcolor{example1!40!black}{\rule[.6ex]{\linewidth}{0.8pt}}\\\noindent},
       spacebelow=\parsep,
       spaceabove=\parsep,
       mdframed={
           linewidth=0.8pt,
           backgroundcolor=example1,
           linecolor=exampleline,
           innertopmargin=6pt,
           roundcorner=5pt,
           innerbottommargin=6pt,
           skipabove=0.3cm,
           innerbottommargin=8pt,
           %skipabove=\parsep,
           skipbelow=\parsep }
]{ExampleStyle}
\declaretheorem[style=ExampleStyle,numberwithin=chapter]{Example}

\makeatletter
\def\ll@Example{%
  \protect\numberline{\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname}%                                                                                                                  
  \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg
    \thmt@thmname
  \else
    \thmt@shortoptarg
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

I really don't understand what Tex is doing. I've tried different things that I found online and nada. Could anyone please assist with this issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue so please add a MWE, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that displays the issue